# Trying to store icons and a corresponding string

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on a a small game. The game consists of displaying 3 random letter from the alphabet and a small icon of something that starts with one of the letters. I was considering using a HashMap but after some research I'm not so sure. I'm not very good with DB's yet so I'm trying to do all the data storage in the application. does anyone  hove a good way of doing this?

Comment: You can store location (like absolute or relative path) to access the icon (assuming its some picture that exists in a folder) as the value of key-value pair in your HashMap. If not, what does icon mean?

Comment: You have to make the question clearer. If you only want to generate a data structure that would let you know which letter and images are generated at runtime, yes, you can use a HashMap.

If you want to store the respective metadata on the disk, I would use a JSON.

Comment: "*I was considering using a HashMap but after some research I'm not so sure*" why? What is your goal and what problems will you face by using HashMap?

Comment: Since I'm only using the letters of the alphabet I know the size of my data structure and the size will never change. For that reason I wanted to avoid using a database. By icons I'm talking about little pictures/images. For example the first pair would A and then a small image of an apple, the second pair would be B and then a small image of a ball. So on through the alphabet. I want to be able to randomly pick a letter and then have the image appear on screen. I found that Kotlin uses HashMap and HashTable but I always thought they were the same thing.

Comment: It isn't clear if you want to store things that survive JVM restarts (from the DB reference) or you just want to store things in memory so they are easier to lookup/reference during the running of the program.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a database for such a scenario. You can store the image and its corresponding letter in it and retrieve them easily. Updating the database would be comparatively easy as well.
You can use a HashMap of Images in the application to enable quick retrieval of the information. The key would the the letter corresponding to the Icon image.